# Write a script to update a nvarchar field to have delimiters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I seem to be having an issue with wrapping my head around how to go about writing an update script and was wondering if someone would be able to help me.

I have a field that has inconsistent data in it that looks something like this:

```
MyField
|123|456|789|
|789|784|154|
879|487|784
789|754|877
```

I need to write a script add the missing `|` in the `beginning` and the `end` of each field. I also need to make sure that it doesn't add the `|` if it is already there.

Would anyone be able to provide me with some assistance?

Comment: Instead of forcing consistent formatting why not properly normalize this instead? Multiple values in a single intersection violates 1NF.

Comment: or you could write a script that stripped the delimiters from the beginning and end...

Comment: @SeanLange - Unfortunately this is not my schema and i currently have to just maintain this. I agree, however, there is not much I can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would much rather see you normalize this instead of causing yourself more pain dealing with a denormalized delimited list but the update is pretty trivial.

```
Update SomeTable
set MyField = case when LEFT(MyField, 1) = '|' then '' else '|' end + MyField + case when Right(MyField, 1) = '|' then '' else '|' end
```

Comment: Good one, sometimes the best answer is just the simplest one

Comment: One thing that i forgot to add is that there can be some fields that do not have anything in them, and they should remain empty. Can you please help incorporate this?

Comment: Just add a where clause to eliminate the rows you don't want to update. where MyField > '' would eliminate NULLS and empty strings. Not sure what else you would require.

Comment: You can also do this.. depending on the SQL Server version. `IIF(LEFT(Val,1)<>'|','|','') + Val + IIF(RIGHT(Val,1)<>'|','|','')`